# WCF: Client-side Mutual Certificate Authentication Problem (Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority)

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

I've done thorough research on my problem and have read many other posts/blogs but their solutions didn't solve mine.  I was hoping someone could help.

I have a very simple WCF service that uses WsHttpBinding Transport Security with Mutual Certificate Authentication.  The server certificate is self-signed certificate and I have confirmed I have the certificate in the trusted store on the client machine.  The server has the client certificate (also self-signed) in the trusted certificate store and I have already verified that I can mutually-authenticate to the service fine using SOAPUI client.

However, I'm not able to do so using the WCF client I created.  On the WCF client, I've set the client certificate by calling the channel factory's Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(...) method and I've also added

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            ( sender,
              certificate,
              chain,
              sslPolicyErrors ) => true;
```

to bypass all possible server certificate problems but I always get: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority server.com.

Can someone please suggest to me what might be the problem and/or what I should do to get this working?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get trying to connect and how does you client code and configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

try this to see if this is only a problem with the certificate trust chain:

http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/12/wcf-gotcha-disabling-ssl-validation.html